I get an extra blankpage when using table environment around tabular
I am currently writing my thesis in a twocolumn environment
For a large table i switched to onecolumn which makes it start on a newpage.
However when i wrap
tabular in a table environment I get an extra blank page before the start of the table. How can i remove this?
\onecolumn

\begin{center}
\begin{table}
   \caption{Table 1}
   \begin{tabular}{l l l c l}
   \end{tabular}

   \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
\end{center}


I didn't expect the extra blank page.
